# Shell Script Moving Files into Folders by Date (i.e. mm-dd-yy) Format

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to create a Shell Script for moving the files whose create time is within 7 days into a folder with same create date's name (i.e. mm-dd-yy) format.

My Script will also be taking 3 inputs (i.e. Path, Archive Indicator and Retention Period)

If the archive indicator has been set to Y, the script will look inside the target directory for any existing files. If the file has a create date time of “01-05-2014 04:25:00”, it will first look for a folder with the date “01-05-2014”. If such a folder exists, it will only transfer the file to the folder. If the said folder does not exist then it will create a folder with the above mentioned name and move the file from the target folder to the sub folder created.

I have tried writing a script but its giving an error, my code is below, please help.

```
!/bin/ksh - *Removed IT*
RETURNCD=0
INUPUTDIRECTORY=${1}
ARCHIVEINDICATOR=${2}
RETENTIONPERIODDAYS=${3}
RETURNCD=$?

if [ ${RETURNCD} != "0" ] ; then
    echo "ERROR: ${RETURNCD} parameter 1 must specify the INUPUTDIRECTORY."
    echo "ERROR: ${RETURNCD} parameter 2 must specify the ARCHIVEINDICATOR."
    echo "ERROR: ${RETURNCD} parameter 3 must specify the RETENTIONPERIODDAYS."
    EXITCODE="1"
    #& goto :END_MAIN
fi
max=$RETENTIONPERIODDAYS
for ((i=1; i<=$max; ++i )) ;
do
TEST1=$(find $INUPUTDIRECTORY/* ! -name . -prune -type f -mtime -$i)
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
  TEST=$(echo $((5 * $i)))
  TEST2=$(TZ=CST+"$TEST" date +%m-%d-%Y)
  TZ=CST+"$TEST" date +%m-%d-%Y | xargs mkdir -p
  cp -rf $TEST1 $TEST2

  else
  echo No Files Present for : 'TZ=CST+$TEST date +%m-%d-%Y'
  fi

done

:END_MAIN
exit ${EXITCODE}
```

---

Comment: Which error is it producing?

Comment: Hi ...Thnx for the help...I updated the for loop a bit but still its failing at "for ((i=0; i<=$max; ++i )) ;" stating :- "0403-057 Syntax error at line 48 : `(' is not expected.". Please Help

Comment: Hi ...I made some progress...its working fine after removing the ksh bash line and some extra "" but now it running 2 times, only creates folder for 2 days then it comes out....Please suggest

Comment: Yes..Its a duplicate..actually I thought its not formatted properly and I am new to Stackoverflow, hence reposted it...can you please help me with this

Comment: Do not repost questions. Instead edit the question to add details, improve formatting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- You need to start the shebang line with `#`, otherwise it's a syntax error.
- Use `mkdir -p` to always try to create the directory. That way you don't have to check whether it exists.
- Use `-eq` rather than `=` to compare numbers.
- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: Hi ...Thnx for the help...I updated the for loop a bit but still its failing at "for ((i=0; i<=$max; ++i )) ;" stating :- "0403-057 Syntax error at line 48 : `(' is not expected.". Please Help

Comment: Hi ...I made some progress...its working fine after removing the ksh bash line and some extra "" but now it running 2 times, only creates folder for 2 days then it comes out....Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

@l0b0's comments plus:

What is the purpose of testing `$?` before you have executed any commands? You probably want:

```
if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: parameter 1 must specify the INUPUTDIRECTORY."
    echo "ERROR: parameter 2 must specify the ARCHIVEINDICATOR."
    echo "ERROR: parameter 3 must specify the RETENTIONPERIODDAYS."
    exit 1
fi
```

To capture the output of a command, use `$()`:

```
TEST1=$(find $INUPUTDIRECTORY/* ! -name . -prune -type f -mtime +"$i")
```

Comment: Hi ...Thnx for the help...I updated the for loop a bit but still its failing at "for ((i=0; i<=$max; ++i )) ;" stating :- "0403-057 Syntax error at line 48 : `(' is not expected.". Please Help

Comment: Hi ...I made some progress...its working fine after removing the ksh bash line and some extra "" but now it running 2 times, only creates folder for 2 days then it comes out....Please suggest

Comment: i have no idea what you mean. please provide all details in your question

Comment: So what happening now is when I am running the script with RETENTIONPERIODDAYS paramter as 5, it creates the folder for today's date (i.e. 02-09-2014) and yesterday's day (i.e. 02-08-2014) and comes  out. No other folders created